# How do store individual inputs inside a for x in range() loop?

Tags: python

```
def location_description():
    '''given the user input for s number of locations, creates s amount of lines to describe each location'''
    location_num = int(num_locations())
    for x in range(location_num):
        input()
```

For example if 3 is inputted, it will create 3 more lines of input. How do I seperately store these 3 items?

Comment: Append them to a list variable.

Comment: In a list, probably would be good.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a list from the input lines:

```
def location_description():
    location_num = int(num_locations())
    lines = [ input() for x in range(location_num) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure to append the input to a returned list:

```
def location_description():
    '''given the user input for s number of locations, creates s amount of lines to describe each location'''
    location_num = int(num_locations())
    lines = []

    for x in range(location_num):
        lines.append(input())

     return lines
```